Join lists of strings in a dataframe column while ignoring null values
I have a DataFrame column consisting of lists of strings and one NaN value. I am trying to join the lists of strings while ignoring the NaN with df.loc, Series.notnull(), and Series.apply(). I expect this to join each of the lists while skipping over the NaNs, but I'm receiving "TypeError: can only join an iterable."
I'm setting up my DataFrame like this:
import pandas as pd

data = {'id': [['54930058LIMFSJIOLQ48'],np.nan,['5493006B6WMKNQ8QNP51 254900425JAG3QVRMM28']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    id
0   [54930058LIMFSJIOLQ48]
1   NaN
2   [5493006B6WMKNQ8QNP51 254900425JAG3QVRMM28]

This is the line I'm using to join the strings. Why is it throwing an error?
df.loc[df['id'].notnull(), 'id'] = df['id'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x))


That second list isn't what you think it is, just so you know. It only contains one string, albeit a string that happens to have a space in it, not two.

The “np.nan” code you entered is the cause of the problem because NaN is not an iterable type. Therefore python issues an error message when you try to run ', '.join(x) on NaN
If you still want to run the code, you can use isinstance to ensure x is a list and you can run the code.
Try this one
df['id'] = df['id'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x)

The code will check x whether it is a list or not. If x is not a list, it will return x itself.

Thank you for explaining - understood! And fixed my script

Glad to hear that, please accept my answer if it helps you to solve the problem

df['id'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x)) is trying to apply ', '.join to all rows, including the one that has a NaN.
Instead you can use something like this:
df["id"] = df.loc[df["id"].notna(), "id"].str[0].str.split().apply(", ".join)

                                           id
0                        54930058LIMFSJIOLQ48
1                                         NaN
2  5493006B6WMKNQ8QNP51, 254900425JAG3QVRMM28


The second value in the column NaN, which is not an iterable and will throw an error if passed to str.join.
Your current solution skips that row on the left side of the assignment, but on the right side (where all the processing is occurring), you're still iterating over the entire df['id'] column, including the NaN.
You could do as e-motta suggested and move the filtering over to the right, but you can also just use the Series.str.join method. It'll handle all the NaNs for you, and is syntactically much shorter:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'id': [['54930058LIMFSJIOLQ48'],np.nan,['5493006B6WMKNQ8QNP51',  '254900425JAG3QVRMM28']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['id'] = df['id'].str.join(', ')
print(df)

                                           id
0                        54930058LIMFSJIOLQ48
1                                         NaN
2  5493006B6WMKNQ8QNP51, 254900425JAG3QVRMM28

